# How to see changes in local working copy in TFS?

Tags: tfs, diff

I'm an experienced SVN user getting used to TFS at a new client site.  The main problem I've had adjusting to the new tool is this - how can I get a listing of all files in my working copy that have changed from current/latest server revision, including added or deleted files?

Essentially, I'm looking for the TFS equivalent of an "`svn diff`".  The "`TF`" command-line tool has a "diff" command which reports changed files but I can't find an option to report deleted or added files; this missing feature has resulted in a couple check-ins which (embarrassingly) broke the build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of TFS?

TFS2010 has a folder compare command, *File > Source Control > Compare...*  (or in the Source Control Explorer, right-click on the project path you're interested in, and select *Compare...*).

Set up the *Source path* to be a folder on the server and the *Target path* to be a local folder in your workspace (or vice versa).  Under *View Options*, select *Show items that exist only in source path*, *Show items that exist only in target path* and *Show items that are different* and click *OK*.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!  We're using VS2008 and that feature is there.  It's a little frustrating that it shows *all* files in the project (not just differences) even though the "Show items that are the same" checkbox is deselected; this results in a lot of scrolling and eyeballing.  Also, it doesn't seem to catch files that were deleted in the explorer...

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you can't use the Source Control Explorer?

If you right click on the folder, project or branch you can click Compare and you will see all files that have been deleted or added.

Comment: If you want to see all changes on a solution, that's the way to go.